# vue.js v-for change from 2 different lists

Tags: vue.js

I want to use different lists. Using vue.js. Some products have list1 and some others have list2. 
I would like to be able to change the source list by tablebody.cel_options from list1 or list2. v-for="f_option in tablebody.cel_options" I have try doing v-for="f_option in" + tablebody.cel_options but it didn't work.

```js
data:{
    tablebody:[
        {cel_options: "list1"},
        {cel_options: "list2"},
    ],
    list1:[
        {text: "option1", value: "options1"},
        {text: "option2", value: "options2"},
    ],
    list2:[
        {text: "option1", value: "options1"},
        {text: "option2", value: "options2"},
    ] 
 }
```

```html
<select class="form-control" v-model="datatable[tablebody.data]" v-on:change="">
    <option v-for="f_option in tablebody.cel_options" v-bind:value="f_option.value">
          {{ f_option.text }}
    </option> 
</select>
```

Comment: Can tou describe more what you want to acrhive

Comment: Sorry. I would like to be able to change the source list by tablebody.cel_options from list1 or list2. v-for="f_option in tablebody.cel_options" I have try doing v-for="f_option in"  + tablebody.cel_options but it didn't work.